# Bootstrap confidence interval with "Inf" in final estimates - boot/dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr, infinite, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to bootstrap a value from a fitted model (maximum slope of curve). Although the code I think could be more efficient I think it generally works (suggestions on how to make it more efficient would also be welcomed). The problem I have is at the end when I have my final sample values where there is `Inf` in one of the cells which prevents me getting a confidence interval. I'm not sure if this is a bootstrap problem or simple from the way I have coded it. Sample code:

```
 library(boot)
 library(dplyr)
 df <- data.frame (id=rep(1:10,each=10),
                      time1=rep(1:10,10),
                      ff=runif(100, 100, 150),
                      gg=runif(100, 120, 170))



    set.seed(10)

#function
    maxx<-function(formula, data,varr,indices)  {
      data <- data[indices,] # allows boot to select sample 
      fit <- lm(formula, data=data)
      data$fit<-fit$fitted.values
      data<-filter(data,time1>5)
      data1<-data %>% group_by_(varr) %>% mutate(derivative = c(NA,diff(fit) / diff(time1))) %>%
        group_by(id) %>%
        slice(which.max(derivative)) %>%
        ungroup()  %>%
        as.data.frame()
      return(mean(data1$derivative,na.rm = TRUE))
    }

 res <- boot(data=df, statistic=maxx, 
                    R=10, formula=ff~gg,varr="id")
```

this works but cannot get SE due to a `Inf` in one of the cells

```
R>res

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = df, statistic = maxx, R = 10, formula = ff ~ gg, 
    varr = "id")


Bootstrap Statistics :
     original  bias    std. error
t1* 0.1726803     Inf         NaN
        res
        res$t
```

We can see this by exploring it further:

```
R>res$t
            [,1]
 [1,] 0.50399242
 [2,] 0.52171509
 [3,] 0.04568459
 [4,] 1.41317481
 [5,] 0.39741115
 [6,] 0.10703703
 [7,] 0.52206909
 [8,] 0.91624253
 [9,]        Inf
[10,] 0.05076168


R>boot.ci(res, type="normal")
Error in ci.out[[4L]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Maybe I missing something but I thought `return(mean(data1$derivative,na.rm = TRUE))` would solve any issues with `NA`. Does anyone have any suggestions please? I am guessing this is a small fix. This is my first time running a bootstrap so apologies if I am doing something naive. If anyone knew how to make the overall code more efficient that would be great as I am running a large random-effects model rather than the simple model presented. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because `boot` resamples with replacement, you may get repeated values of *time1* for a given *id* within a given sample. When this happens, your derivative calculation `diff(fit)/diff(time)` evaluates to 0/0, which should return NaN. NaN values should not be inherently problematic for the rest of your `maxx` function (though I'm not completely clear on what you're trying to do), but I suspect that due to floating point inaccuracy `diff(fit)` sometimes returns nonzero values that get divided by zero to produce Inf or -Inf. The `which.max` and `mean` functions do not ignore Inf, and so your `maxx` function occasionally returns Inf.